# How to run a batch command in Windows as a different user without typing the password?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a simple windows batch command as a one-liner on a windows command prompt, without having to specify the password. The user is named 'alex', so I am trying:

```
>cmd /C echo PASSWD | runas /profile /user:alex "cmd /c dir"
```

but I get the following error:

```
Enter the password for alex:
Attempting to start cmd /c dir as user "ALEX-NEU\alex" ..
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd /c dir
1326: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

where `ALEX_NEU`  is the machine name. The user name and the provided password are correct - so why do I get this error? How to do it correctly?

Comment: You cannot. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx. You would have to write your own program to do it as mentioned in that blog. There is [an ugly hack](http://techtorials.me/windows/using-runas-with-a-password/) that does not look promising. If the users' password is in the credentials manager you may [also be able to do this](http://serverfault.com/questions/7620/windows-run-as-without-knowing-the-password). However, this question belongs on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to supply the password to `runas` at runtime is with a script, and not terribly gracefully either.  It's ugly, it's hackish, and it's asking for security troubles.  Having said that, I've done something similar in the past with `WScript.Shell`'s `.run` and `.SendKeys` methods like this:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /* multiline JScript comment

:: runas.bat
:: runas with automated password entry

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "USER=username"
set "PASS=password"
set "CMD=cmd /c dir && pause"

:: delayed expansion prevents special characters from being evaluated
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" !USER! !PASS! !CMD!

goto :EOF

:: end batch portion / begin JScript portion */

for (var i=0, args=[]; i<WSH.Arguments.length; i++)
    args.push(WSH.Arguments(i).replace(/"/g, '^"')); // escape all quotes

var user = args[0],
    pass = args[1],
    cmd = ' "' + args.slice(2).join(' ') + '"',
    oShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");

oShell.run('runas /noprofile /netonly /user:' + user + cmd);
WSH.Sleep(500);
oShell.SendKeys(pass + '{ENTER}');
```

This is a hack, only a proof of concept, and is largely untested.  I have no idea whether it'll handle "quoted arguments" in the `!CMD!` variable.  I daresay if you want to use it for practical applications, you'll have a great deal of revising and debugging in your future.

There are a couple of other [embellishments to this method](http://xinn.org/RunasVBS.html) you might consider.