# How to create a jenkins job in order to perform VBoxManage operations on virtual images?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I want to setup a jenkins job in order to e.g. clone a virtual image. The (working) command line is e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevm UbuntuTest --name TestNeu --register
```

However, the same command line executed in jenkins as window batch script does not work, it gives an error

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'UbuntuTest'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszSrcName).raw(), srcMachine.asOutParam())" at line 434 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

I only can suppose this jenkins script runs as a different user and does not know of the available images located in `C:\Users\alex\VirtualBox VMs`.

How to fix this problem?

Addendum:

- Running this as a different user does not seem to work or is impossible: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079314/how-to-run-a-batch-command-in-windows-as-a-different-user-without-typing-the-pas)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your Jenkins slave process to run as the desired user.
First install Jenkins slave as a Windows service , then go the service properties and in the 'Log On' tab change it from the default 'Local System Account' to "This Account:" - enter your account name (alex) and password. 
Don't forget to restart the service.